# Programming with Dynamic

Tags: programming, dynamic, faq

I don't understand the following:

```
  f[a_, b_] := a + b
  ls = {1, 2, 3};
  MapThread[f, {ls, {10, 20, 30}}]
```

This yields ( as expected ) {11,22,33}

If I change the code to

```
  f[a_, b_] := a + b
  ls = {1, 2, 3};
  MapThread[f, {Dynamic[ls], {10, 20, 30}}]
```

mma returns the following message:

```
  MapThread::mptd: Object {1,2,3} at position {2, 1} in MapThread[f,{{1,2,3},{10,20,30}}] has only 0 of required 1 dimensions. >>
```

**Question: Why does this happen? How can it be fixed?**

Comment: The first gives me `{f[1, 10], f[2, 20], f[3, 30]}`; I suppose you cut and pasted the wrong thing!

Comment: Already changed it, sorry !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even though `Dynamic[ls]` is presented as `ls`, its head is `Dynamic`:

```
x = Dynamic[ls]
Head[x]
(*
{1, 2, 3}
Dynamic
*)
```

or

Basically, `Dynamic` is a wrapper, and is there even if you cannot see it. Its like you were writing

```
MapThread[f, {symb, {10, 20, 30}}]
```

with `symb` undefined, or

```
MapThread[f, {Integrate[symb[var], var], {10, 20, 30}}]
```

You can fix it by doing

```
Dynamic[MapThread[f, {ls, {10, 20, 30}}]]
```

instead.

So:

Wherever you had written `Dynamic[ls]`, you still have `Dynamic[ls]`. It may be displayed by the frontend as `{1,2,3}`, but it is not; it's `Dynamic[ls]`. So, `MapThread` goes to look at the first part of its second argument and sees `Dynamic` instead of a `List`, so it stops and emits a message; this message includes `Dynamic[ls]` in it. When the message reaches the "surface" to be displayed, `Dynamic[ls]` gets automatically interpreted by the frontend as usual: it's displayed as `{1,2,3}`, because that's what `ls` evaluates to. But it is still `Dynamic[ls]`, not `{1,2,3}`, *which is simply how it is displayed*.

Try this: `Do[Sin[i], Dynamic@{i, 1, 2}]` and think about what happens...

Comment: Sorry, I don't get this. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I still don't get, but it WORKED. Dynamic still has its mysteries to me. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 8):

#### `Dynamic` doesn't work the way you think it does.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1581155/618728) for a full explanation.

In short, `Dynamic` doesn't do anything until it is actually displayed on screen.
Therefore, you are essentially doing this (note the String):

```
MapThread[f, {"Dynamic[ls]", {10, 20, 30}}]
```

As acl already showed, you can wrap the entire expression in `Dynamic` so that it does not attempt to evaluate the failing condition shown above.

Comment: Can we move here the linked topic?

Comment: @Kuba You mean migrate the question form Stack Overflow?  No, that's not done anymore.  There was a one-time offer to migrate important questions when they introduced the new policy, but now nothing over 30 (or 60?) days old can be migrated.

Comment: Pity, thanks for info. Your answer and linked topic are quite broader than the scope of this question. And often I'm linking this topic because of your answer really. A generic one would be nice.

Comment: @Kuba Ask John Fultz to do a self-Q&A on this site to share that information, along with any updates he might want to make since 2009.  If he is too busy we can just do a CW post and quote that one verbatim.

Comment: Feel free to do that, I'm not so motiviated at the moment, maybe I will be soon. I will try to not forget that and do this when another broader but closely related question appears.