# How can I seperate specific elements from the list?

Tags: dynamic, modular-arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about MapThread and Dynamic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5817/question-about-mapthread-and-dynamic)

I write a function name as `inputFieldsList` and it returns both `InputFields`and `InputFieldValues`with in single list.

```
inputFieldsList[kl_] := 
   (inputvaluelist = Table[0, {kl}];
    {
    Table[
            (
            With[{i = i},
                (InputField[Dynamic[inputvaluelist[[i]]], Number, 
    ContinuousAction ->
                True, ImageSize -> {50, 20}, Alignment -> Center])
                    ]
            ),
            {i, 1, Length[inputvaluelist]}
              ],
    Dynamic[inputvaluelist]
    }
   )
```

calling that Function

```
result = inputFieldsList[5]
```

TestCases:

case1:

```
       Part[result, 1]
```

case2:

```
         Part[result,2]
```

case3:

```
        Part[result,1,1]
```

case4:

```
      Part[result, 2,1]
```

case4 is not working....

why it is not working?

How can I extract specific element from the second element of the `result`?

can anybody help me?

Comment: Check `result[[2]] // FullForm`.

Comment: I want to extract any specific element from the second element of the `result`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Part[result /. Dynamic -> Identity, 2, 1]
```