# Dynamic ImageHistogram

Tags: image-processing

I want to plot dynamic "`ImageHistogram`" from by using  my pc web camera

I tried this:

```
i = Dynamic[CurrentImage[]]

ImageHistogram[i]
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question about MapThread and Dynamic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5817/question-about-mapthread-and-dynamic)

Answer (score 3):

```
Dynamic@ImageHistogram@CurrentImage[]
```