# Hovering over specific coordinates on a picture

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, dynamic

[image: Edit: This image shows what I am working on, I know the coordinates of each of the points, and they have a separate list of names for each one.]

I'm working on a small function which can be used so that when the user hovers over certain coordinates in a LocatorPane, these coordinates can be checked against a separate list of coordinates, and there can be different graphical outputs on a separate graphic, depending on what coordinates the user has hovered over.

```
ttp = LocatorPane[Dynamic[userEditedProbeCoordinates], tmp, 
Appearance -> (probeDissFunc[WorstcaseDistressWTT16, probeList])]

coordinates = Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics"]]
```

This get's me the coordinates from the user.

```
If[coordinates - 893, 368 < {\[PlusMinus]10, \[PlusMinus]10}, yay, boo]
If[coordinates == 893, 368, hooray, stop]
If[coordinates \[Subset] userEditedProbeCoordinates, woop, nooooo]
```

Here are 3 of my attempts to make something happen. None of them were successful.

The list of coordinates looks like this:

```
{{893, 368}, {863, 327}, {885, 512}, {800, 502}, {766, 360}, {710, 
374}}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all [**5820**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5820/5478), then also: `PlusMinus` has no built in meaning.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this without `LocatorPane`. Let's start by creating test data:

```
SeedRandom[25];
pts = RandomReal[200, {10, 2}];
labels = RandomInteger[1000, 10];
map = Deploy@Graphics[{
     Disk[#, 10] & /@ pts,
     PointSize[Large], Red, Point[pts]
     }, PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {0, 200}}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is important to specify the plot range explicitly, as we will use this in the next step. I use `Deploy` so the graphics can't be selected, which is appropriate for a display. The black disk represents the area of radius ten around the point, represented by a red dot.

```
nf = Part[labels, Nearest[pts -> Automatic, #, {1, 10}]] &;
EventHandler[map, {
  "MouseMoved" :> (hovering = nf[200 MousePosition["EventHandlerScaled"]])
  }]
```

In the previous step we initialized a list `labels`. Element 1 is the label for disk 1, element 2 for disk 2 and so on. Here we define a function `nf` that, given a coordinate, returns the label of the closest point within a radius of 10. Finally we use an event handler to update a variable `hovering`. `MousePosition["EventHandlerScaled"]` gives a position `{x,y}` where x and y are in the range (0,1) inside the graphic. Multiplying this by the plot range we get the actual coordinate inside the graphic.

[image: Demo]

As the animation shows the label of the currently hovered point can now be retrieved by `Dynamic[hovering]`. This value can be displayed anywhere it's needed, in the graphics or elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

As an example

```
img = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5]}, ImageSize -> 300];

tag[p_] := Piecewise[{{"Red", Norm[p] < 0.5}, {"Blue", 0.5 < Norm[p] < 1},
           {"White", Norm[p] > 1}, {"Boundary", Norm[p] == 0.5 || Norm[p] == 1}}]

csign[{x_, y_}] := StringForm["[``,``]", Sign[x], Sign[y]]

Manipulate[Show[img,PlotLabel -> StringForm["`` ``", tag[p], csign[p]]],
           {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

**With multiple locators**

```
n = 6;
col = {Black, Red, Blue, Green, Orange, Yellow};
txt = {"Black", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Orange", "Yellow", "Empty"};
rad = {0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 10};
img = Graphics[Table[{col[[i]], Disk[{0, 0}, rad[[i]]]}, {i, n, 1, -1}]];

tag[p_] := Piecewise[ Table[{txt[[i+1]], rad[[i]]<Norm[p]<rad[[i+1]]}, {i, n}]]

coord = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];

Manipulate[Show[img, ImagePadding -> 20,  Epilog -> {
 Text[tag[p1], p1 + {0, 0.1}], Text[tag[p2], p2 + {0, 0.1}],
 Text[tag[p3], p3 + {0, 0.1}], Text[tag[p4], p4 + {0, 0.1}]}],
 {{p1, coord[[1]]}, Locator}, {{p2, coord[[2]]}, Locator},
 {{p3, coord[[3]]}, Locator}, {{p4, coord[[4]]}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Comment: Sumit, Thanks for the example, do you know how I can convert this to coordinate based Plotlabels? So if the cursor is in within + or - 10 of a certain coordinate, some separate information can appear on a separate graphic next to it?

Comment: you can define a new function for that. I modified my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks so much, but I am using a LocatorPane rather than a graphic, how can I incorporate this in to my already displayed LocatorPane? Sorry I am really new to mathematica, and need some simple way of checking the cursor's location against a list of coordinates, to see if it is within + or - 10 of it radially. I have added in a picture of my LocatorPane to my post.

Comment: I modified my answer for multiple locator. Hope that will help. You can choose the initial coordinates for the locator from your list of coordinates.

Comment: Thanks that's really useful. Can you help me with one last step though? My code is now `tag[p_]:=Piecewise[{{Part[probeList,1],Norm[p -{5,5}-Part[userEditedProbeCoordinates,1]] < 10}}]
Manipulate[Show[rttp,PlotLabel->tag[p] ],{{p,{0,0}},Locator}]` , but I need to repeat part of it for values from 1 to the Length of one of the lists. So in normal code speak this would be `tag[p_]:=Piecewise[{{Part[probeList,n],Norm[p -{5,5}-Part[userEditedProbeCoordinates,n]] < 10}, for n from 1 to Length[probeList]}] `, but I don't know how to do this in Mathematica. Is this possible?

Comment: have a look at the modified answer.

Comment: This is great, thanks Sumit. Is there a way to extract the PlotLabel (or Epilog) As a separate variable which I can use? So instead of Green or Orange just being the PlotLabel etc, I can use an If function later (i.e. If[(new variable from PlotLabel) = "Orange", "This is Orange"]

Comment: yes. Just define a new variable. say `Manipulate[s = p1; Show[img,...`