# Dynamic input for Complex, Determinant output problems

Tags: matrix, dynamic, complex

I'm having trouble using `Complex` with `Dynamic` real and imaginary inputs.  The inputs come from a matrix of popup menus:

```
InitA = {
    {PopupMenu[Dynamic[a11re], Range[-5,5]] + PopupMenu[Dynamic[a11im], Range[-5,5]] Style["i", Italic], PopupMenu[Dynamic[a12re], Range[-5,5]] + PopupMenu[Dynamic[a12im], Range[-5,5]] Style["i", Italic]},
    {PopupMenu[Dynamic[a21re], Range[-5,5]] + PopupMenu[Dynamic[a21im], Range[-5,5]] Style["i", Italic], PopupMenu[Dynamic[a22re], Range[-5,5]] + PopupMenu[Dynamic[a22im], Range[-5,5]] Style["i", Italic]}
        };
```

Using those dynamic inputs, I set the parts of a new matrix equal to those dynamic inputs.

```
a11 = Complex[Dynamic[a11re], Dynamic[a11im]];
a12 = Complex[Dynamic[a12re], Dynamic[a12im]];
a21 = Complex[Dynamic[a21re], Dynamic[a21im]];
a22 = Complex[Dynamic[a22re], Dynamic[a22im]];
A = {{a11, a12},
    {a21, a22}};
```

For some reason, the matrix `A` isn't read as 4 complex numbers, but just four inputs of the form `Complex[Re, Im]`. If I remove the `Dynamic[]` around the variables when using `Complex[]`, A displays 4 complex numbers in `TraditionalForm`.  Does anyone know about the behavior of `Complex` that restricts it from using dynamic inputs?

**EDIT**

Later in the application, `Det[A]` must be found.  Using JM's suggestion for creating the complex numbers in `A`, with initial inputs of `A` as:

```
a11re = 2; a11im = -4; a12re = 2; a12im = 0;
a21re = 3; a21im = 0; a22re = 5; a22im = -3;
a11 = Dynamic[a11re + I*a11im];
a12 = Dynamic[a12re + I*a12im];
a21 = Dynamic[a21re + I*a21im];
a22 = Dynamic[a22re + I*a22im];
```

`Det[A]//TraditionalForm` outputs "2-4i5-3i-23", which is (2-4i)(5-3i)-(2)(3) without the parenthesis. Why would it not evaluate the determinant fully? That just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Use an explicit construction instead: `Dynamic[a11re + I a11im]`.  `Complex` requires explicit numbers (i.e. satisfies `NumberQ[]`).

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: take a look here: [85491](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85491/5478) and at a possible duplicate: [5820](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5820/5478)

Comment: Condensing into a comment: `1` is a number and can be used everywhere where a number is expected.  `Dynamic[1]` is not a number and cannot be used in such places.  `Dynamic[expr]` is a way to *display* `expr` and automatically recompute it any time a subpart changes.  Things wrapped in `Dynamic` cannot be used for computation.  If it's a determinant you want to display and update dynamically, `Dynamic` must appear *once*, wrapping `Det`.

Comment: Thank you Szabolcs! That did the trick! Also thanks to J.M. for his initial response!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to J.M. and Szabolcs for addressing my questions clearly. Here's what they came up with:

I was using `Dynamic` incorrectly, wrapping variables that weren't being displayed.

The new code is now this

```
InitA = {
    {PopupMenu[Dynamic[a11re], Range[-5,5]] + PopupMenu[Dynamic[a11im], Range[-5,5]] Style["i", Italic], PopupMenu[Dynamic[a12re], Range[-5,5]] + PopupMenu[Dynamic[a12im], Range[-5,5]] Style["i", Italic]},
    {PopupMenu[Dynamic[a21re], Range[-5,5]] + PopupMenu[Dynamic[a21im], Range[-5,5]] Style["i", Italic], PopupMenu[Dynamic[a22re], Range[-5,5]] + PopupMenu[Dynamic[a22im], Range[-5,5]] Style["i", Italic]}
        };

a11 = a11re + I a11im;
a12 = a12re + I a12im;
a21 = a21re + I a21im;
a22 = a22re + I a22im;
A = {{a11, a12},
    {a21, a22}};

Dynamic[Det[A]]
```