# How to make 3D image of dynamic current image

Tags: image-processing, image3d

How to make a 3D image of `Dynamic[CurrentImage[]]`?

for example:

```
img= Entity["Building", "EiffelTower::5h9w8"][
EntityProperty["Building", "Image"]]

Image3D@Rest@NestList[EdgeDetect, ImageResize[img, 500], 10]
```

[image]

I tried :

```
Image3D@Rest@NestList[EdgeDetect, ImageResize[Dynamic[CurrentImage[]], 500], 10]
```

but there is an error message

Comment: Move `Dynamic` outside. [Programming with Dynamic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5817/5478)