# How to evaluate `Dynamic` expression?

Tags: dynamic

I am trying to work my way through `Dynamic` but there is something I dont get and I would appreciate very much some clarification. Consider the following code

```
Manipulate[
 var1 = Dynamic@par1;
 im1 = Graphics[Circle[], Axes -> True];
 locd = Dynamic[locator];
 pointOK = Dynamic[locator + {-1, 1}];
 pointWRONG = locd + {-1, 1};
 Grid[{
   {"[1.1]", par1 + 2}
   , {"[1.2]", var1 + 2}
   , {"[1.3]", Evaluate[var1 + 2]}
   , {"[1.4]", ReleaseHold[var1 + 2]}
   , {"[2.1]", LocatorPane[locd, im1]}
   , {"[2.2]", locd}
   , {"[2.3]", pointOK}
   , {"[2.4]", pointWRONG}
   , {"[2.5]", Graphics[{
      PointSize -> Large
      , Blue, Point@pointOK
      , Red, Point@pointWRONG
      }, PlotRange -> 2, Axes -> True]}
   }
  , Alignment -> Left
  ]
 , {par1, 0, 1}
 , {{locator, {0, 0}}, None}
 ]
```

[image]

For different reasons I would like to have a manipulable parameter `par1` and perform some alebraic operations on variables defined on it, like in [1.1] in the picture above. But, if, just out of fun, I declare a symbol `var1 = Dynamic@par1` and try to perform some algebra on it, like in [1.2], it does not get evaluated. I read that `Dynamic` has `HoldFirst` and I thought that `Evaluate` would help me, as I tried in [1.3], but without luck. The same for `ReleaseHOld`, [1.4].

The weird thing for me is now that `Point` (and surely other functions) is able to evaluate this kind of expressions. Consider the `Locator` in [2.1] based on the `locator` control and the symbol `locd = Dynamic[locator]` now. If I want to some algebra on the momentary values of `locator`, I have to do it like in the symbol `pointOK`, [2.3], and NOT as in symbol `pointWRONG`, [2.4], since the `Dynamic` object is "added" to each element of the list `{-1,1}`. Nevertheless, in the last graphic, `Point` is able to process `pointWRONG`, otherwise you would not see the 2 red points.

So, what property has `Point` or what do I need to evaluate expressions containing `Dynamic` objects (such that, e.g., I get the same in [1.1] and [1.2])? Thank you!

**EDIT:**
Compared to the question [Programming with Dynamic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5817/programming-with-dynamic), I think this question deals more with the question on how to evaluate an expression containing a `Dynamic` object (if `Dynamic` could not be evaluated numerically, then `Point` would not be able to display anything, but you can see the points in my plot). In [Programming with Dynamic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5817/programming-with-dynamic) I had the feeling that it was important to understand that the head of `Dynamic[x]` is `Dynamic`. But some evaluation has to be possible even if objects like `Integer` and `Dynamic`, again, otherwise `Graphics@Point@pointWRONG` would not work.

Comment: Dynamic doesn't evaluate. And when displayed Dynamic[x]+1 you will just see 1+1 (if x=1). And Graphics@Point@Dynamic@x doesn't evaluate Dynamic either, it is the front end that knows the Point @ Dynamic @ x should be rendered as a point with coordinates given by x.

Comment: @Kuba : Ou... so it is a special property of `Point` (and surely other built in functions) to identify `Dynamic` and evaluate it internally? (see my edit)

Comment: No, `InputForm@ToBoxes@Graphics@Point@Dynamic@x` take a look. When written to notebook there is no `Point`, just `Boxes`. The `FrontEnd` cares about rendering them. E.g. that `FrameBox` is a rectangle with a frame. So it cares about `Dynamic` it know it has to know its current value for display purposes, and if in GraphicsBox it is interpreted accordingly, but in no case Dynamic evaluates. The FrontEnd just takes the content of Dynamic and evaluates it but as a "separate" evaluation which is a part of rendering process, not the evaluation of the original expression.

Comment: @Kuba hmmmm .... ok, I think I get the point, but I have to digest it. Thanks! Should I delete the question?

Comment: I don't know, maybe it is not a duplicate at the end. And in each case it should stay as a separate question or marked duplicate, for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you need to have a dynamic object that does some calculations, and what you want is to get to the value of the actual expression defined as a function of a dynamically changing parameter (*par1* in your case), than you can simply do that by extracting that expression from a variable defined with the [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) head.

```
var1 = Dynamic[par1 + 1];
Slider[Dynamic@par1, {0, 10, 1}]
Dynamic[var1 + 3]
Dynamic[var1[[1]] + 3]
```

[image]

The first object is not evaluated (it still has a `Dynamic` head, so it can't be added to the value of 3, but notice that 1 was added to *par1* inside `Dynamic` when it was pushed to the FE, so it is displayed as 2), but the second one is evaluated once we remove the `Dynamic` wrapper.

In addition, as Kuba suggested, an alternative to [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)is [`Setting`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Setting.html). Both extract the first argument, which is important if the [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html)has multiple arguments, since the expression you are interested in is in the first one.

Comment: @Kuba Agree, `Evaluate` is not particularly interesting. I will update. `ReleaseHold` would still be needed if you have a function with `Hold`, isn't it? Anyways, the point I was trying to communicate is that you can replace the `Dynamic` with anything needed to properly evaluate the expression inside `Dynamic`.

Comment: Sorry for being picky. I just want to avoid confusion for new users, I remember how I was once overwhelmed by all this stuff.

Comment: @Kuba Not at all! Thanks for your comments! I agree it might be confusing, you have an excellent example.

Comment: @Kuba : guys, thank you very much for the discussion and explanations, it helps to understand a lot. A lot I have to learn as a young padawan :D

Comment: @MauricioLobos ,Kuba Thank you guys! I am learning myself from our jedis :)