# DateTime Input Dialog in Mathematica

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, dialog-window, scheduling

I am trying to create a `DateTime` input dialog that will return a `DateTimeObject`

```
DateTimePopup[] := 
  CreateDialog[
   DynamicModule[{date = {0, 0, 0}, th, tm, ts}, Column[{Row[{
        TextCell["Date:"], Spacer[5], 
        Developer`DateSetter[Dynamic[date]], Spacer[40],
        TextCell["Time:"], Spacer[5], 
        PopupMenu[
         Dynamic[th], # -> "H:" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[0, 24]],
        PopupMenu[
         Dynamic[tm], # -> "M:" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[0, 59]],
        PopupMenu[
         Dynamic[ts], # -> "S:" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[0, 59]]
        }],
      Row[{
        Dynamic[
         DateObject[Sequence@Flatten@Append[date, {th, tm, ts}]]], 
        Spacer[10],
        DefaultButton[
         DialogReturn[
          Dynamic[DateObject[
            Sequence@Flatten@Append[date, {th, tm, ts}]]]]]
        }]
      }]], WindowSize -> {400, 200}];
```

When I try to use that function I get a popup but I expected the expression to evaluate after I `DialogReturn`

```
dt = DateTimePopup[]
```

> ```
>  NotebookObject[FrontEndObject[LinkObject["dtt6m_shm", 3, 1]], 46]
> ```

But I get a return immediately. How can I get the date time object returned from the dialog ?

Comment: Use `DialogInput` and drop `Dynamic` from `DialogReturn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want a dialog to return a value for a purpose of currently running evaluation you need to use one of *kernel blocking* dialogs:

  ```
  DialogInput, ChoiceDialog, Input
  ```
- Otherwise `CreateDialog` and friends will just popup a window but the current evalaution will proceed without caring about it. Of course you can put `DefaultButton[myVar=15;DialogReturn[]]` and `myVar` will get that value once `OK` is clicked but it will be asynchronous with respect to the main evaluation.

It is up to you what to use, each can be useful. E.g. Cloud login dialog is a kernel blocking one since subsequent evaluation needs those credentials while Preferences dialog is not because it does not matter when will you change some FE settings.

The first method requires you to change `CreateDialog`, the latter to pass the variable. I suppose you want the former.

Additionaly, drop `Dynamic` from `DialogReturn`, otherwise you will get `Dynamic[expression]` and will run into the problems like OP there: [programming-with-dynamic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5817/programming-with-dynamic)