# Trouble with evaluation and Dynamic

Tags: dynamic, evaluation

I would like to evaluate the gradient of a certain function at position (x0,y0,z0) where x0, y0, z0 are global variables which can get altered in real-time later in the worksheet. The only way I know of doing this, without pain, is using Dynamic (is there a better way?)

But there is something strange going on, Mathematica doesn't want to evaluate the components of my gradient vector into actual numbers.

```
f := z - x*y;
x0 = 1; y0 = 2; z0 = 1;
mygradient := {D[f, x], D[f, y], D[f, z]};
normalizedgrad := mygradient/Sqrt[mygradient.mygradient];
n := normalizedgrad //. {x -> Dynamic[x0], y -> Dynamic[y0], z -> Dynamic[z0]};
```

Now,

```
 n
```

produces

```
{-2/Sqrt[1+3^2+2^2], -3/Sqrt[1+3^2+2^2], 1/Sqrt[1+3^2+2^2]}
```

and I am unable to numerically evaluate this. If I write

```
N[n]
```

then I just get back the same as n.

Comment: Take a look at [Programming with Dynamic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5817/5478). For preview use `Dynamic[n]` and drop `Dynamic` from `//.`. Since you define `n` with `SetDelayed` it will be up to date when requested and `Dynamic[n]` will refresh based on `x0` value change etc.

Comment: Ok, many thanks!