# use of PopupMenu

Tags: popup

I have the following code:

```
PopupMenu[Dynamic[choose], {al, bl, cl}]
```

and

```
vin1 = Dynamic[choose]
```

then, I would like to use such value in a conditional expression `If`:

```
If[vin1==al, 3 x + 2, 6 y]
```

But only `vin1` is automatically updated. `If` doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you seen PopupMenu documentation? Where are you stuck? Do you wan't to run `If` manually later or automatically?

Comment: I set `PopupMenu[Dynamic[choose], {al, bl, cl}]` and then `vin1 = Dynamic[choose]`. Furthermore `If[vin1 == al, al + bl, cl + bl]`. But `If` doesn't work.

Comment: I see, if you manually evaluate `vin1 = choose` it works. If you want everything to be connected in some kind of gui then you need to explain what do you expect and when. But for Shift+Enter `vin1=choose` is enough.

Comment: I have edited my code.

Comment: So can you remove the Dynamic I told you or?

Comment: Is this the answer or is there something more that is missing? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5817/5478

Comment: Solved: I set `"al"` instead of `al`, as well as for `bl` and `cl`, in the definition of PopupMenu and in `If`

Comment: I don't think so: `Dynamic["al"] == "al"`

Comment: `PopupMenu[Dynamic[choose],{"al","bl","cl"}` and then `If[chhose== "al", 3 x + 2, 6 y]`

Comment: So you did remove `Dynamic`, great, btw, use `===` to compare arbitrary expressions.